# When rendering a view no function clause matching in Ecto.assoc_loaded?/1 error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm rendering a view but it is throwing error while association loading. Not sure what I'm missing. Been breaking my head but unable to find solution.

Matter of fact it was working fine before with `Phoenix 1.3.0` and now run into this problem after upgrading `Phoenix to 1.6.15`

**user_controller.ex**

```elixir
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    current_user = conn.assigns[:current_user]
    user =
      case is_nil(current_user) do
        true ->
          from(
            m in Media,
            left_join: u in assoc(m, :user),
            left_join: o in assoc(u, :organization),
            where: m.id == ^id and m.type == ^:default and is_nil(u.deactivated_date),
            select: %{
              id: m.id,
              title: m.title,
              description: m.description,
              ....
              user: %{
                u
                | is_followed: false,
                  organization: %{
                    id: o.id,
                    name: o.name,
                    address: o.address
                    .....
                    }
                },
              }
            }
          )
          |> Repo.one()
       
      false -> .....
   end
   
  conn |> render("show.json", user: user)
end
```

**user_view.ex**

```elixir
def render("show.json", %{user: user}) do
    %{
      id: user.id,
      email: user.email,
      first_name: user.first_name,
      last_name: user.last_name,
      account_type: user.account_type,
      username: user.username,
      organization:
        if Ecto.assoc_loaded?(user.organization) do
          render_one(user.organization, OrganizationView, "organization.json", as: :organization)
        else
          nil
        end
     }
end
```

Comment: Please post the full error message that you're getting, and what you're doing that triggers it.